# fatal: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: git, ssl, heroku

While deploying a flask app on heroku using heroku CLI, I encountered this error :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/app_name.git/': 
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number.
```

As I am a noob to the heroku as well as the deployment side, any leads are appreciated.

Comment: What operating system are you using and what version of Git?

Comment: I am using windows 10
git --version: git version 2.20.1.windows.1